# Overlay2 driver is not supported

Tags: docker

When I run command `sudo systemctl start docker` I get an error

```
failed to mount overlay: invalid argument storage-driver=overlay...failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: driver not supported
```

`daemon.json` file looks like that

```
{
  "storage-driver": "overlay"
}
```

and I use Ubuntu 21.10.

I can't use zfs instead of overlay/overlay2 so this is not a workaround for me.

Comment: What is the kernel version and the underlying filesystem for /var/lib/docker (show the line from `mount` that specifies `/var/lib/docker` or a parent folder, e.g. `/` if no other filesystems are mounted in `/var`)?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly but kernel version used by me is: `5.13.0-30-generic` and I have one folder in  `/var/lib/docker`, that is `zfs`

Comment: Please include the output of `mount` in your question.